# How to add a dot in the package.json file using npm-pkg command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to use the [npm pkg set command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-pkg) to generate a package.json file like this:

```
{
  ...
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/my-lib.js",
      "require": "./dist/my-lib.umd.cjs"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

But I'm not able to add the "." key

I tried running `npm pkg set exports..import=./dist/my-lib.js` and `npm pkg set exports.\.import=./dist/my-lib.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a property directly in json format:

```
npm pkg set exports='{".":{"import": "./dist/my-lib.js","require": "./dist/my-lib.umd.cjs"}}' --json
```

Please note that this will overwrite existing "export" property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `["."]` (the quotes are not strictly necessary but looks cleaner), this way the other existing exports will not be removed:

```
npm pkg set exports["."].import="./dist/my-lib.js"
npm pkg set exports["."].require="./dist/my-lib.umd.js"
```

or with `--json` (which is needed if you want to reorder the conditions):

```
npm pkg set --json exports["."]='{"import":"./dist/my-lib.js", "require":"./dist/mylib.umd.js"}'
```